# Shell script random number generating

Tags: bash, shell, variables, random

`var=$RANDOM` creates random numbers but how can i specify a range like between 0 and 12 for instance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you already have your random number, you can say

```
var=$RANDOM
var=$[ $var % 13 ]
```

to get numbers from `0..12`.

**Edit:**
If you want to produce numbers from `$x` to `$y`, you can easily modify this:

```
var=$[ $x + $var % ($y + 1 - $x) ]
```

Answer (score 8):

Between 0 and 12 (included):

```
echo $((RANDOM % 13))
```

---

**Edit**: Note that this method is not strictly correct. Because 32768 is not a multiple of 13, the odds for 0 to 8 to be generated are slightly higher (0.04%) than the remaining numbers (9 to 12).

Here is shell function that should give a balanced output:

```
randomNumber()
{
  top=32768-$((32768%($1+1)))
  while true; do
    r=$RANDOM
    [ r -lt $top ] && break
  done
  echo $((r%$1))
}
```

Of course, something better should be designed if the higher value of the range exceed 32767.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative using shuf available on linux (or coreutils to be exact):

```
var=$(shuf -i0-12 -n1)
```

Comment: Meh. Then your script isn't portable.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
echo $(( $RANDOM % 12 ))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Correction: $(( $RANDOM % 13 ))

Comment: yes, agreed, thanks. I was so excited to get to answer an easy one first, I didn't test closely enough! Thanks for the 2 up-votes (whoever you are) ;-)

Comment: Note the inner $ is optional as non numeric strings found there cannot be but variable names.

Answer (score 1):

This document has some examples of using this like RANGE and FLOOR that might be helpful: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html

Answer (score 1):

On FreeBSD and possibly other BSDs you can use:

```
jot -r 3 0 12
```

This will create `3` random numbers from 0 to 12 inclusively.

Another option, if you only need a single random number per script, you can do:

```
var=$(( $$ % 13 ))
```

This will use the PID of the script as the seed, which should be mostly random. The range again will be from 0 to 12.

Comment: Mac OS X has jot too. But not Linux, so this isn't portable.