# $RANDOM in Bash doesn't work

Tags: bash, random

Where could be the problem in this script?

```
#!bin/bash
NUMBER=$RANDOM
echo " The number is: $NUMBER"
```

when I start this script, it'll write this:

```
The number is:
```

(I am running Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: What happens when you just do `echo $RANDOM` in your current shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have an error in your shebang, it should be :

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(note the missing `/`)

Comment: It'll write just this 
" The number is:  "

Comment: for me this always returns 0 for me when I run my script with `sh` and not `bash`. Why is that?

Answer (score 10):

Finally I find a reason why it might not work for you.

The reason is probably that you run your script as (sh myScript.sh) to make it works try (bash myScript.sh)

Comment: for me this always returns 0 for me when I run my script with `sh` and not `bash`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Probably:
You have extra spaces where they don't belong  This is correct:

```
NUMBER=$RANDOM
```

when you actually type it into bash or in your script, this is not correct:

```
NUMBER =$RANDOM
```

And a shebang error in the real script makes the script print 'File not found' and exit early with no other output.  That is not the error reported I believe.

Please check your script very carefully.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for confusing previous message because the $$ is something absolutely else

but I found some alternative solution for this problem:
to generate random number from 0 to 12 use:
var=$(shuf -i0-12 -n1)

original source:
[Shell script random number generating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992638/shell-script-random-number-generating)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem... for me was working (in script)
instead of: "echo $RANDOM"
try: "$$"

Comment: `$$` is the PID of your current script, not some random number ! And it will obviously stay the same until the end of the script, no matter how many times you call it.

Comment: for me this always returns 0 for me when I run my script with `sh` and not `bash`. Why is that?